# "Failed to read the status of the response" - Error logging into Azure Sql Management Portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-management

My cloud service (Asp.Net MVC) is able to connect to the Azure Sql database successfully.

But I am unable to login to the Azure SQL Management Portal.

I get an error "Failed to read the status of the response".

Can anyone help please?

Comment: It has been 2 days. Same issue. So I am managing with Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio to update the database.

Comment: I waited for several days until the problem was resolved. I think the Azure team fixed something from their side.